# how can this patent be valid?

Tags: us20160299031

In reference to the patent: [US20160299031](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160299031A1/en)

This patent has claims such as:

1. The apparatus of claim 1 where the acoustic tracking system is comprised of at least one pinger and at least three hydrophone base stations; where the acoustic tracking system tracks the location of the automated tank surveyor in the vessel.

Yet, this is trying to patent common subsea positioning technology called USBL or LBL, developed in the 90's

4. The apparatus of claim 3 where the automated tank surveyor is powered up only when it is below a pre-determined exclusion zone.
5. The apparatus of claim 3 where the automated tank surveyor is powered down when it is above a pre-determined exclusion zone.

This is a commonly used method of creating explosion proof devices, and used for 20+ years

1. The apparatus of claim 1 where the automated tank surveyor is further comprised of a sediment plow.

Tank plows have been in use for 20+ years

1. The apparatus of claim 1 where the acoustic tracking system is comprised of at least one multi-beam phased array; where the multi-beam phase array is steered in a pre-determined pattern.

multi-beam phased arrays (3d sonars) are decades old.

Most of this patent is not valid due to prior art.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, the cited document is a patent application. It is not yet a patent and might never be granted. Second, you cite several claims, but all of them are dependent claims. This means they refer to a different claim. A dependent claim is limited by the scope of the referenced claim. Claim 1 is as follows:

> 1. An apparatus to test the integrity of a vessel comprising an automated tank surveyor mobilizing at least an ultrasound measurement
>      system and acoustic tracking system.

Every claim that refers to claim 1 is limited in scope to an apparatus used to test the integrity of a vessel as described. None of the claims tries to patent "common subsea positioning technology called USBL or LBL". Nor is claim 6 in any way trying to generally patent tank plows.

> 6. The apparatus of claim 1 where the automated tank surveyor is further comprised of a sediment plow.

This claim is adding a specific case of claim 1. The fact that the invention is utilizing ultrasound transducers does not mean it is trying to patent the general use of ultrasound detectors. Lasers were invented decades ago, but new uses of them are still being invented.

Now, none of what I've written means that I necessarily believe this application is patentable, only that your concerns are a bit overblown. It is common for applications to have broader claims than are eventually granted. Claims can be amended and most always are based on rejections by the patent examiner. Patents like this one where existing technologies are combined are usually open to rejection due to "obviousness". This is where the examiner will reject claims based on the idea that someone with normal skill in the field would find it obvious to combine said technologies. If you go to the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site, get past the CAPTCHA you can search for this application by selecting "Document Number" and entering "20160299031". If you click on the "Transaction History" tab you can see the application has received a non-final rejection. This doesn't mean it won't become a patent, just that the claims, as written, have failed to convince the examiner of their merit. There is now a process of negotiation where claims are amended and explanations made to try to circumvent the objections. If you click on the "File Wrapper" tab, you can actually read the communications between the applicant and the examiner and see, for instance, what the examiner's objections were and the subsequent response.